# Find the first reoccuring char from a String

Tags: java, strings, hash-map

Can anyone give me advice on how I can improve my answer?
I have tested it out using "ABCA", "BCABA" and "ABC".
Two things I would like help on.
1.How can I move this code into a method
where it returns the reoccurring char? I know how to return the char once it has been found but what about the case where there is not char what do I return back in that case? Since I cannot return char.
2. Is using the break statement bad practice? I noticed that the code would with "BCABA" both "B" and "A" are printed.

Thanks.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "BCABA";

    Map<Character, Integer> recurringCharsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (char character : testString.toCharArray()) {
        if (recurringCharsMap.containsKey(character)) {
            System.out.println("Recurring char is: " + character);
            break;
        } else {
            recurringCharsMap.put(character, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Having a method with `Character` return type (instead of the primitive `char`) allows you to return `null` when no recurring character is found.
- Instead of using `break`, you can return the first recurring character you find. If none are found, return `null`.
- You don't need a `HashMap` (unless you want to count the number of occurrences of each character, which you don't). Use a `HashSet` instead.

  ```
  public static Character findFirstRecurringChar (String input) {  
      Set<Character> recurringChars = new HashSet<>();
      for (char character : input.toCharArray()) {
          if (!recurringChars.add(character)) { // add will return false if character is
                                                // already in the Set
              return character; // return the first recurring character
          }
      }
      return null; // no recurring characters
  }
  ```

Then you can call the method with:

```
public static void main (java.lang.String[] args) {
    System.out.println (findFirstRecurringChar ("BCABA"));
}
```

Comment: @Snowbody That's not required in Java 7 and later (Java can infer the parameter type).

Comment: Yep, just saw that in the docs. Time for me to get back up to speed on Java.

Comment: I think it would be better if ‘!recurringChars.add(character)’ is extracted and placed in a method isRecurring(character, recurringChars) (maybe there is a better name for this) to imrpove the readability of the code. Also, instead of returning null, I think you should return a blank character in case there are no recurring characters.

Answer (score 2):

The `Character` type already has everything you need. It is either a character or the special value `null`.

For this task you don't need a map, a simple set is enough.

When you move this code into a separate method, using `break` becomes bad style because you should directly `return`. In the currect code it's ok.

```
public static Character findFirstRecurring(String str, char ch) {
    // Left as an exercise
    …
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String`s in Java are Unicode, stored as UTF-16. This means that Unicode code points from the BMP (U+0000 to U+FFFF) are represented as one `char`, but Unicode code points from the SMP (U+10000 to U+10FFFF) are represented as a pair of `char`s from special ranges. For instance, Chinese characters. So if you just look at individual `char` you may get bad results if there is more than one SMP code point in the string (and if an SMP code point is the one repeated, you'll return a completely wrong value). The proper way to do this is to look at code points.

I'm basing off of Eran's answer.

```
public static int findFirstRecurringCodePoint (String input) {  
    Set<Integer> usedCodePoints = new HashSet<>(); // int representing a Unicode code point
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        int codePoint = input.codePointAt(i);
        if (!usedCodePoints.add(codePoint) {  // add() will return false if code point is
                                              // already in the Set
            return codePoint; // return the first recurring character
        }
        if (codePoint > 0xFFFF) {
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    return -1; // no recurring code points
}
```

Comment: You should change `Set<int>` to `Set<Integer>`. Java doesn't support primitive generic type parameters.